# Deserializer is not parsing the JSON string

Tags: json, vb.net, class, deserialization

My class is not being populated with the JSON string

Using the VS 2012 Edit -> Paste Special -> JSON as a CLASS

The Class Created:

```
Public Class clsMCParcelData
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property ParcelFound As Boolean
    Public Property ParcelInfo As New APN
End Class
Public Class APN
    Public Property Book As String
    Public Property Map As String
    Public Property Item As String
    Public Property clean As String
    Public Property formatted As String
    Public Property link As String
End Class
END CLASS
```

JSON String:

```
{
    "ParcelFound":true,
    "APN":{
        "Book":"510",
        "Map":"11",
        "Item":"668",
        "clean":"51011668",
        "formatted":"510-11-668",
        "link":"\/api\/parcel\/51011668"
        }
            }
```

Code on the asp.vb page:

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer, MCD As New clsMCParcelData.Rootobject
MCD = jss.Deserialize(Of clsMCParcelData.Rootobject)(raw)
```

I would expect that once deserialized, I would be able to access the APN information like so:

```
tbParcelNumber.text = MCD.ParcelInfo.formatted (returning 510-11-668)
```

What I get is Nothing as the value of MCD.ParcelInfo.formatted

Comment: Seems fine to me, how about the other properties, do they have values?

Comment: Found it.  switched APN and ParcelInfo.  Now the JSON string is deserializing correctly.

Comment: Glad you did it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScriptSerializer requires an exact match in the class to deserialize.